# Given a criteria function. Why two integral of cumulative function $\integ{F_1-F_2$ can be combine and the magic of triangle inequality

Tags: probability, triangle-inequality

I have been studied a research for many days, but I have been confused by mathematical inequalities. I list the calculations as below and explain the notations.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|{\hat{Q}}_N\left(\gamma,F_1\right)-{\hat{Q}}_N\left(\gamma,F_2\right)\right|\le2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\pi_{ijt}\left|\int{g_j\left(x_i,\beta,\gamma\right)\left(dF_1\left(\beta\right)-dF_2\left(\beta\right)\right)}\right|}{NJT}
+\frac{1}{NJT}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\int{g_j\left(x_i,\beta,\gamma\right)\left(dF_1\left(\beta\right)+dF_2\left(\beta\right)\right)}\\ \times|\int{g_j\left(x_i,\beta,\gamma\right)\left(dF_1\left(\beta\right)-dF_2\left(\beta\right)\right)|}
\\ \le4\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left|\int{g_j\left(x_i,\beta,\gamma\right)\left(dF_1\left(\beta\right)-dF_2\left(\beta\right)\right)}\right|/NJT
\end{split}
\end{equation}

${\hat{Q}}_N$ is the criteria function.
\begin{equation}
{\hat{Q}}_N\left(\gamma,F_1\right)=\frac{1}{NJ}\sum_{i=1}^N\left\|y_i-\int g(x_i,β)dF(β))\right\|_E^2=\frac{1}{NJ}\sum_{i=1}^N\left\|y_i-\sum_{r=1}^Rθ^rg(x_i,β^r)\right\|_E^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}

$\pi_{ijt} = [0,1]$
$\gamma$ is the distribution parameter for $F$
$g(x_i,\beta,\gamma)$ is a choice probability

Thnaks for reading this very long equations.
I understand the second inequality holds due to that $y_i,g_j(x_i,\beta,\gamma)  and \int g_j(x_i,\beta,\gamma) dF(\beta)$ are uniform bounded by 1.

My questions are below：

1.Why two integral of cumulative function $\int g(\cdot) dF_1-\int g(\cdot) dF_2$ can be combine into $\int g(\cdot) (d(F_1-F_2))$

2.According to the paper, the first inequality holds by using of triangle inequality. I can't link the triangle inequality with this form. Is it related to  $\int g(\cdot) (d(F_1-F_2))$ and $\int g(\cdot) (d(F_1+F_2))$ ?

Hope anyone can help me understand the mathematical calculation.
Thanks.

Comment: In order to understand $\int g(\cdot) dF_1-\int g(\cdot) dF_2=\int g(\cdot) (dF_1-dF_2)$, consider that $dF_1=g_1(x)dx$ and $dF_2=g_2(x)dx$  for certain functions $g_1, \ g_2$ (which is the case for most applications when you don't have "diracs" in the pdf generating "jumps" in the cdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie It seems to be very basic, but I still need to make sure that if it means that I should break $dF_1 = g_1(x)dx$. Then the function becomes $\int g(\cdot)g_1(x)dx$ ?

Comment: That's right. $g_1$ is a particular kind of jacobian.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry but I don't really understand  ∫g(⋅)g1(x)dx  and ∫g(⋅)(dF1−dF2)
maybe I need more explanation to understand.
Besides, can I ask you why the first inequality is related to triangle inequality？